# Prove that this covering map is a homeomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p \colon E \to X$ be a covering map. Let $s \colon X \to E$ be continuous. If $p \circ s = \operatorname{id}_{X}$, show that $p$ is a homeomorphism.

We know that $p$ is a continuous surjection. Since all covering maps are open, we just need to show that $p$ is an injection. How is this done?

Comment: Does "Let $p \colon E \to X$ be a covering map" include connectedness of $E$ in the definition? Without something like that, it would be false, consider $E = X\times\{0,\,1\}$ with $p$ the projection onto the first factor.

Comment: Ah, yes. For simplicity, just assume that both $E$ and $X$ are connected and locally path-connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ah, yes. For simplicity, just assume that both $E$ and $X$ are connected and locally path-connected.

Let $x,\, y \in E$ with $p(x) = p(y)$. Since $E$ is path-connected (follows from connected and locally path-connected), there is a path $\gamma$ connecting $x$ and $y$.

$\beta := p\circ \gamma$ is a closed path in $X$. $\gamma$ is a lift of $\beta$, and $s\circ \beta$ is also a lift of $\beta$. By the uniqueness of lifts, $\gamma = s\circ \beta$.

But $s\circ \beta$ is of course a closed path, hence $y = x$.

Comment: That all makes sense. Thanks so much, Daniel!